# how pass arguments to kubernetes yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes

how to use same yaml for multiple job runs?
here snippet of yaml file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    version: 0.0.1
  name: batch
  labels:
    app: batch
    io.service: batch
  namespace: batchnamespace
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: batch-1
        image: batch:001
        args: ["progname","arg1","arg2"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

How to achieve soemthing like "kubectl apply -f job.yaml programname arg1 arg2" ie,, use same yaml file to run different jobs?

Comment: helm? kustomize? envsubst? ....

Answer (score 0):

You mean running different pods using same container?
In that case you need to create a bash  file and then use sed command to change the name of pod.
I am using @multi-pod so it can be detected in bash sed command.
Lets say my yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: @multi-pod
  name: @multi-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: machlovi/tf_threading:latest
    name: "p1"
    env:
     - name: type
       value: demo1
```

Then I will create a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
  
x=1
# here i have set the num pods 5 which can you change as per need
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
        # $1 argument is yaml file like tf.yaml 
        #sed command look for @multi-pod and then replace it with p1, p2 
        # till p5
        template=`cat "$1" | sed "s/@multi-pod/p$x/g"`

       
        x=$(( $x + 1 ))

        echo "$template" | kubectl apply -f -
   
done
```

Run the bash file like:
bash test.sh tf.yaml